# Proof verification for complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I turned this proof in for homework and think it may have several flaws.
In the forward direction of the implication is it okay to divide by $r_2$ and assume $r_2$ is nonzero?Also in the backwards direction is it okay to divide by $z_2$?

Prove $\text{arg}{z_1}=\text{arg}z_2$ if and only if $z_1=cz_2$ where $c>0$

Attempt:

$\text{let} z_1=r_1(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$,
$z_2=r_2(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$

Thus $\frac{z_2}{r_2}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta \implies z_1=\frac{z_2r_1}{r_2}$

Let $c=\frac{r_1}{r_2}$ then $z_1=cz_2$

Conversely suppose $z_1=cz_2 \implies c=\frac{z_1}{z_2}$

$\implies \text{arg}\frac{z_1}{z_2}=\text{arg}c \implies \text{arg}z_1-\text{arg}z_2=0 \implies \text{arg}z_1=\text{arg}z_2$

Comment: Indeed you can assume $r_1,r_2\neq0$ because $\arg 0$ is not well-defined

Comment: Argument of $0$ is not defined. So assume that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are non-zero which implies that $r_1 >0$ and $r_2 >0$.